# Fast wired network in a large building

Tags: routing, ethernet, gigabit-ethernet, wired-networking, signal-strength

As everyone knows, ethernet wiring is faster than any WiFi and more secure to boot.

Using Cat 8 ethernet cabling can currently provide the best networking speeds where the switches and router can take those speeds, but there is another limitation besides switches and routers, as with all ethernet connections.

[Cat 8 is limited to 30m cabling length with 25 Gbps or 40 Gbps whereas Cat 7 is limited to 100m with 10 Gbps](https://www.sfcable.com/blog/cat-7-vs-cat-8-cables-difference). After these distances, the signal degrades leading to slower connections.

**What if the distance required is further than 30m?**

Moving the internet connection and router to the centre of the building and spidering the connections outward would probably be a best option but will not be practical.

[TechAdvisor](https://www.techadvisor.com/how-to/network-wifi/how-speed-up-your-home-network-wifi-3787559/#toc-3787559-8) like many other sites, talks of meshed WiFi to boost WiFi signals throughout a building. But, nowhere that I can find, has any information about boosting ethernet signals.

If using Cat 8, will adding switches boost the signal at the 30m connection limit or will the 30m include both lengths of Cat 8?

If switches don't boost the signal, is there anything else that would?

Comment: Do you REALLY need 40Gbps for all client machines?

Comment: @spikey_richie not necessarily all machines all the time, but if any of them need to transfer large amounts of data to or from the server, then a fast connection will get the job done more speedily.

Comment: What’s wrong with fiber? It’s what everyone uses, and has been using for decades.

Comment: Yeah, CAT5/6/7/8 have always been the "final link" cables of choice going from comms cupboards to actual machines. If you want distance as well as speed then fibre cables, while easy to damage, have far better range. For example 40Gig 10km: https://www.fs.com/uk/products/36171.html Copper has a problem in that you have to deal with cable resistance and power loss but is better for things that change often or are more temporary. Fibre is always going to win in situations where it's "install and ignore".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use copper cabling in the first place; roll fiber Ethernet everywhere. Good single-mode fiber will support 40 Gbps for up to several kilometers, and if your switches go that fast, they most likely *will* have an SFP+ or other appropriate port for fiber optic modules. (For servers, there are PCI-E cards with SFP+ ports available too.)

(Twinaxial cable is apparently also a thing – there is "direct attach copper" which also connects to the switches' SFP ports… I thought that was just for short distances but Google says *apparently* they make it for up to a few km, so it might do the job?)

> If using Cat 8, will adding switches boost the signal at the 30m connection limit or will the 30m include both lengths of Cat 8?

The distance is up to the nearest switch, not end-to-end. Most switches completely terminate the physical signal; they actually receive the Ethernet frames at link layer and send them back out again to the correct port (i.e. "store and forward").

Comment: Yes; Run fiber to individual switches then copper the rest of the way unless you need fiber speeds the entire run.

Answer (score 1):

Just found [the answer at NetworkEngineering.SE](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/11322/75871)

Talking about Cat 7:

> Add an Ethernet switch in middle of link, splitting the link into 2 parts, <=100m each; ethernet switches can regenerate the signal. FYI, the switch even can be powered by PoE from one of sides. (e.g. a Mikrotik RB260G)

So, while a switch doesn't boost the signal *per se*, it regenerates the signal therefore it allows you to transmit at the highest speed over a greater distance.

https://community.cisco.com/t5/switching/how-to-use-switch-to-boost-signal-on-multiple-long-cat-5-runs/td-p/2070712 says the same.

https://superuser.com/a/1323813/581166 gives you the answer but without this explanation.

Another option would be to do away with copper ethernet cable over the distance and add fibre-optic.

> Change the copper UTP cable to Single-Mode Fiber. It solves not only the distance problem, but it also eliminates possible problems due to different electrical potential between buildings.

You can get switches with combination of fibre-optic and copper ethernet connections.

[image: 10/100/1000M switch]